# Texture gets reduced or flattened at object corner and part of an object

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders

The texture I applied gets (1) reduced or flattened at the corner area of the backrest, where the corner faces the camera. And it gets (2) reduced or flattened at about one fourth of the armrest facing the camera. How can I avoid this?

[image: rendering]

[image: settings]

Comment: have you checked the UV?

Comment: What can I do / should I do with the UV?

Comment: maybe pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sorry, the file is 1.04 GB big and it doesn't let me do any changes, because my Blender always crashes (also with older files) since two hours ago. So I cannot make it smaller. PasteAll needs a file smaller than 24 MB. What can I do to prevent these shutdowns? Should I reinstall Blender?

Comment: or don't pack the images and just share the object so that we can check the UVs?

Comment: The error doesn't occur after I copied the object into a new Blender file. The mapping is perfect on all surfaces. Why does this happen?

Comment: hard to say, again, please share your file

Comment: Hello moonboots, I uploaded a test version with only one chair to pasteall.org. The problem doesn't occur in this one but the UV/mapping settings are the same as in my primary file. How do you get my upload?/Users/gaborlengyel/Desktop/Blender_Sessel_Test_UV_upload_2021-04-11_1055.png.    https://pasteall.org/blend/4e87bc9466e6485f95ed45471f7c7640

Comment: yes weird because it doesn't seem to be any problem in the file you share, if you put a grid texture it seems to project correctly (a bit stretched, that's all)